# simple javascript/ajax call - does not return status

Tags: javascript, ajax

The following code produces nothing on the html page, it seems to break down on 'status':

```
var get_json_file = new XMLHttpRequest();
get_json_file.open("GET", "/Users/files/Documents/time.json", true);
**document.write(get_json_file.status);**
```

keep in mind, that I am on a Mac, so there is no C: drive....however, this line of code does work fine:

```
document.write(get_json_file.readyState);
```

I just want to know that I was able to successfully find my json file. Perhaps, I should ask, what should I be looking for to achieve what I want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only get the status when the ajax has finished. That is, when the page was loaded, or a 404 was returned.

Because you're trying to call `status` straight after the request was sent *(or not sent, read the P.S)*, you're getting nothing.

You need to make an async call, to check that status only when the request finishes:

```
get_json_file.onreadystatechange = function (){
    if (get_json_file.readyState==4 && get_json_file.status==200)
    {
        alert('success');
    }
}
```

read more at http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp

**P.S** as noted by @Oscar, you're missing the `send()`.

---

If you want to try a synchronous approach, which would stop the code from running until a response is returned, you can try:

```
var get_json_file = new XMLHttpRequest();
get_json_file.open("GET", "/Users/files/Documents/time.json", false);
//notice we set async to false (developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)
get_json_file.send(); //will wait for a response
document.write(get_json_file.status);
//(Credit: orginial asker)
```

Comment: i noticed this code did work - when I changed that true to false., how do you explain that ?

Comment: Indeed. if you're willing to let your code stop, you can set the `async` to `false`. That way, the javascript will wait for a response for the `send()` method to finish

Answer (score 2):

Another basic question about AJAX. I suggest you to read the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/XMLHttpRequest) about using XMLHttpRequest. You can't access the 'status' property until it is ready, and you haven't even called the 'send()' method, which performs the actual request. You can't have a status without making an HTTP request first. Learn how AJAX works before trying to use it. Explaining it all would be too long and this is not the place.

Answer (score 0):

Because of security issues you are not allowed to send requests to files on the local system, but what you could do is look into the fileReader API. (more info [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/))

```
<sidenote>
The reason that the readyState works and not status is because by defualt 
readyState has a value of 0 and status has no value so it would be undefined.
</sidenote>
```

Answer (score 0):

in my ubuntu, the path will be prefixed with file:///

i think your json file path should have file:///Users/files/Documents/time.json, because mac and ubuntu based on unix

and then you can check ajax status using @TastySpaceApple answer

if you using google chrome, don't forget to launch it with -–allow-file-access-from-files command, because google chrome not load local file by default due to security reason